# how to restrict to use application to specific number of user in android programatically

Tags: android, google-play, restriction

I am developing an application and as per client requirement i want to give restriction to use that application to specific number of users and if the application is uninstalled by any user then, the count of users should be decreased and new user can be able to use that application. For E.g if we give 5 users to use the application and if any user uninstall the  application then, new user means 5th user can use applicatio

Comment: please elaborate more!

Comment: You won't be able to detect uninstall easily.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved in many ways -

1. Is there any kind of login mechanism involved in your app? If yes then grant login to your desired users.
2. Create an API which will check device identification whenever user opens your app.

Hope this helps...

Comment: can you tell me how to create api ?

Comment: There are multiple architectures available for API development, one of the most popular one is RESTful architecture. Please refer https://github.com/panique/simple-php-api

Answer (score 0):

You can create API for device identification. Also,
to check whether application uninstalled. You can take use of GCM Push notification.

Read more here:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#how-uninstalled-client-app-unregistration-works

"An application can be automatically unregistered after it is uninstalled from the device. However, this process does not happen right away, as Android does not provide an uninstall callback."

Basically, when GCM tries to send the next push notification, the device will tell GCM the receiving application was uninstalled.

Comment: what will solution application not using gcm notification?

Comment: I think integrating GCM will solve the problem of counting how many users using your application. I don't know other ways to find whether an application is deleted or not. Sorry :(